# Confusion on fluid dynamics Bernoulli's equation problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

I couldn't get answer in the choices in this question I started solving by using
Continuity equation $$A_1V_1=A_2V_2$$
And calculated $V_1$=1.6 m/s

Then i used Bernoulli's equation
$$\frac{F}{A_1}+\frac{1}{2}\rho V^2=\rho gh+\frac{1}{2}\rho V_2^2$$
Now when I plug in the values and calculate the force i get a number which isn't in the choices what did I do wrong?

($\rho$ is the water density, $\rho=1000 kg/m^3$ and $V$ is the velocity of the water is the density $A_1$ is the area on which the force is applied and $R_1=50cm$ ,$A_2$ is the area from which the water exits the cylinder (2) $R_2=20cm$)
[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by you using $p$ in the equation, because I am expecting $\rho$ as a density. Please correct this and re-evaluate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

On the right side of Bernoulli's equation, h = 1m, $V_2$ = 10 m/sec, and you need to include the atmospheric pressure (where the fluid leaves cylinder 2). The other (h) on the diagram comes from treating the water leaving cylinder 2 as a projectile.